# Selecting a fragment to start with in ViewPager - Android

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I am trying to make a Login screen where the Register, Login and Forgot Password screens are all fragments, placed like this:

Forgot Password | Login | Register

I found a simple video on YouTube showing me how to do this. The only issue I have is that when I start the Activity, it opens on the Forgot Password fragment since it is the first one, but I am wanting it to start in the middle, the Login fragment. Here is the code for the main activity. What should I change or add to this code or am I taking the wrong approach for what I am trying to achieve

Access.java

```
public class Access extends FragmentActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.access);

        initializePaging();
    }

    private void initializePaging() {
        List<Fragment> fragments = new Vector<>();
        fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this, AccessForgotPassword.class.getName()));
        fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this, AccessLogin.class.getName()));
        fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this, AccessRegister.class.getName()));

        PagerAdapter mPagerAdapter = new PagerAdapter(this.getSupportFragmentManager(), fragments);

        ViewPager accessViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.accessViewPager);
        accessViewPager.setAdapter(mPagerAdapter);
    }

}
```

access.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/accessMainLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".access.Access">

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/accessViewPager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
    </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

</LinearLayout>
```

AccessForgotPassword.java

```
public class AccessForgotPassword extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        if (container == null) {
            return null;
        }
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.access_forgot_password, container, false);
    }

}
```

access_forgot_password.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/accessForgotPasswordMainLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="#FF0000">
</LinearLayout>
```

AccessLogin.java

```
public class AccessLogin extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        if (container == null) {
            return null;
        }
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.access_login, container, false);
    }

}
```

access_login.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/accessLoginMainLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="#00FF00">
</LinearLayout>
```

AccessRegister.java

```
public class AccessRegister extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        if (container == null) {
            return null;
        }
        return inflater.infalte(R.layout.access_register, container, false);
    }

}
```

access_register.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/accessRegisterMainLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="#0000FF">
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set

```
accessViewPager.setCurrentItem(1);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try adding  `accessViewPager.setCurrentItem(1)` in end of `onCreate()`

Answer (score 1):

Try to set `accessViewPager.setCurrentItem(1);` in the onCreate() of your activity.

Answer (score 1):

Just after setting adapter you can set manually set the second fragment to view pager

```
accessViewPager.setCurrentItem(1); // 0= ForgotPassword, 1=LoginScreen,...so on
```